# Parse callback going into done(Object, Throwable) instead of done(ParseObject, ParseException)

Tags: android, parse-platform, callback

I'm trying to use Parse for an Android app right now, and I want to do something with a `ParseObject` after it finishes saving to the server. The callback should be calling `done(ParseObject, ParseException)`, but for some reason, it goes into the `done(Object, Throwable)` method instead. Any clue why?

```
ParseObject event = new ParseObject("Event");
event.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // code in here should be executing
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void done(Object o, Throwable throwable) {
        // but instead, code in here is actually executing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SaveCallback` doesn't return `ParseObject`. it's only give you `Exception` if occured while saving object at `parse.com`

```
ParseObject event = new ParseObject("Event");
    event.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try to this way.

```
        ParseObject event = new ParseObject("Event");
    event.put("hear Class Field name", "hear new value from user input");
    // before u want to save in background set user psermission for read &
    // write like this way
    ParseACL postACL = new ParseACL(ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
    postACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
    postACL.setPublicWriteAccess(true);
    event.setACL(postACL);

    event.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {

        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (e == null) {
                // hear u will get success message
            } else {
                // and hear u will get fail message
                // also get which error throw like
                Log.e("testing ", "get error code " + e.getCode()
                        + " get Error Message " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```